# How to put the sum of a cell at a cell in another table mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, workbench

Maybe the title is a little confusing but I will try to explain. I am trying to simulate the database of a telephone company. Among the tables I created, my interest is in these 3 tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`number` (
        `MSISDN` BIGINT(10) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
        `CUSTOMER_NUMBER` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
        PRIMARY KEY (`MSISDN`) COMMENT ''
    );



     CREATE TABLE `test`.`bill_msisdn` (
    `BILL_ID` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
    `MONTHLY_FEE` DECIMAL(10 , 2 ) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
    `CHARGES` DECIMAL(10 , 2 ) NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT '',
    `TOTAL_BILL` DECIMAL(10 , 2 ) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
    `MSISDN` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`BILL_ID`) COMMENT ''
);

     CREATE TABLE `test`.`bill_customer_number` (
    `BILL_ID_CUSTOMER` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
    `CHARGE_DATE` DATE NOT NULL COMMENT '',
    `TOTAL_BILL` DECIMAL(10 , 2 ) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
    `CUSTOMER_NUMBER` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`BILL_ID_CUSTOMER`) COMMENT ''
);
```

I filled these 3 tables with a little data to see if it works.
For the first table I wrote the following because I wanted to have 2 customers, the first with 2 numbers and the second with only one:

```
INSERT INTO number VALUES (6944747844,1234567);
INSERT INTO number VALUES (6944747845,1234567);
INSERT INTO number VALUES (6944747846,7654321);
```

For the second table I wrote:

```
INSERT INTO bill_msisdn VALUES (12345,10.50,0,MONTHLY_FEE+CHARGES,6944747844);
INSERT INTO bill_msisdn VALUES (12346,11.5,5.22,MONTHLY_FEE+CHARGES,6944747845);
INSERT INTO bill_msisdn VALUES (12347,3.10,9.02,MONTHLY_FEE+CHARGES,6944747846);
```

The MONTHLY_FEE+CHARGES i entered at TOTAL_BILL basicaly sums MONTHLY_FEE and CHARGES automatically.

What I do not know how to manage is at the third table (bill_customer_number)

I wrote:

```
INSERT INTO bill_customer_number VALUES (12345678,'2015-09-15',,1234567);
INSERT INTO bill_customer_number VALUES (12345679,'2015-09-13',,7654321);
```

leaving the TOTAL_BILL column, empty.

My question is if there is a way, to automatically calculate the TOTAL_BILL of each customer based on how many MSISDN's has.

For example customer 1234567 has two numbers ( 6944747844 and 6944747845). How can I fill automatically the column TOTAL_BILL of this line

```
INSERT INTO bill_customer_number VALUES (12345678,'2015-09-15',,1234567);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be with help of subqueries?

```
 INSERT INTO bill_customer_number VALUES (12345678,'2015-09-15',
 ( SELECT SUM(TOTAL_BILL) FROM bill_msisdn WHERE MSISDN = 1234567 )
 ,1234567);
```

Comment: not exactly, but you showed me the way to do it . I just added one more column to bill_msisdn (CUSTOMER_NUMBER) and i wrote        INSERT INTO bill_customer_number VALUES (12345678,'2015-09-15',( SELECT SUM(TOTAL_BILL) FROM bill_msisdn WHERE CUSTOMER_NUMBER = 1234567),1234567);

Comment: Coll! I could confuse what parameter and where will go because it is everywhere 12345(678)  =) , but I knew that you can understand me. If it was useful, you may mark it as answer =)